# Grunt: abstracting away some tasks

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm

I have a project with a lots of grunt-tasks that are basically building a full featured asset pipeline (transforms, sourcemaps, minification, md5 filename visioning). Most of this tasks are opensourced tasks i've found on github but there are also some that I've just "inlined" with `grunt.registerTask`.

Now i want to create a second Project that also uses this tasks, but I couldn't find the right way how to create a npmTask for Grunt that uses other tasks, because it fills like Grunt was never designed for this. How to create something like this? Maybe there are some projects on github that have done something like this and I could have a look at their design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and load your own grunt task - it's actually pretty easy.

1. Create the task - the official documentation has an example that calls two other tasks: http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks. Put the below in your `Gruntfile`:

   ```
   grunt.registerTask('hello', function() {
     grunt.log.write('hello');
     grunt.task.run(['task1', 'task2'])
   });
   ```
2. Then move that task in its own file and folder (like `tasks/hello.js`), with a touch of wrapper code

   ```
   'use strict';

   module.exports = function(grunt) {
     grunt.registerTask('hello', function() {
       grunt.log.write('hello');
       grunt.config.set('task1.opt1', 1234);
       grunt.task.run(['task1', 'task2'])
     });
   };
   ```
3. Then load the tasks folder in your `Gruntfile.js`

   ```
   grunt.loadTasks('tasks');
   ```

Comment: thanks, in my case the `'hello'` task needs to have the configuration for `'task1'` and `'task2'` (right now the configuration is provided via `grunt.initConfig()`) otherwise we just abstracted around 2 or 3 lines of the  initialisation, instead of 100 lines of config code.

Comment: The config is accessible straight on the grunt object: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#accessing-config-data - I edited my answer with an example

Comment: thank you so much, i will try to use `grunt.config.merge` because don't want to rewrite my configs in this weird dot syntax